# How to wrap a formula inside a table to decrease the column width and increase the row thickness

Tags: tables, equations

I have a table in which the last column has a wide formula.
Do you know how we can wrap a formula inside a table to decrease the column width and increase the row thickness:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=2pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{my_example}{EXAMPLE}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
This is my first table:
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline $x$ &  $y$   &  $z$ & $x \circ y$ & $x \circ z$ & $\left(x \circ 
y\right)\oplus\left(x \circ z\right)$ &  $\left[\left(z \circ 
x\right)\oplus\left(x \circ z\right)\right] \circ \left(z \circ x\right)$\\
\hline $a$&$b$ &$c$ &$d$ &$e$&$f$&$g$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
{\caption{my first table}} \label{table_first}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document structure isn't entirely clear. The natural width of the textblock would appear to be 7in, but you're trying to shoe-horn things into a block that's only 2.25in wide. Please clarify the purpose of the narrow `adjustwidth` environments.

Comment: @Mico the purpose of having the adjustwidth is to get a customized margin on some especial pages to help reader take notes on the relatively wide margin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aligned` environment to split any formula over a number of lines. I also used an `array` instead of a `tabular` as all you have is maths.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=9.8125in,paperwidth=8in, left=.5in, 
right=.5in,top=.75in,bottom=.4375in }
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pag}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{exampledefault}{linewidth=2pt}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{my_example}{EXAMPLE}[chapter]
\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
This is my first table:
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{adjustwidth}{2.25in}{0pt}
\begin{center}
$
\begin{array}{|*7{c|}}
\hline x & y & z & x \circ y & x \circ z & (x \circ y)\oplus(x \circ z) & \begin{aligned} & [(z\circ x) \oplus (x\circ z)] \\ & \qquad\circ (z\circ x)\end{aligned} \\
\hline a & b & c & d         & e         & f                            & g\\
\hline
\end{array}
$
{\caption{my first table}} \label{table_first}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Edit:** Even better, as suggested by @Mico, you can use the `gathered` environment from `mathtools` package (supersedes `amsmath`) and the code will be further simplified:

```
$
\begin{array}{|*7{c|}}
\hline x & y & z & x \circ y & x \circ z & (x \circ y)\oplus(x \circ z) & \begin{gathered} [(z\circ x) \oplus (x\circ z)] \\ \circ (z\circ x)\end{gathered} \\
\hline a & b & c & d         & e         & f                            & g\\
\hline
\end{array}
$
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask what \qquad does?

Comment: `\qquad` is a horizontal space equivalent to `hspace{2em}` and is used to indent the second line.

Comment: Thank you AboAmmar!

Comment: +1. For greater simplicity, maybe use a `gathered` environment (requires the `mathtools` package) instead of the `aligned` environment and omit the two `&` alignment points and the `\qquad` directive?

Comment: Sure, thanks, I added your suggestion.